# Extremely high intercept from Elastic Net

Tags: scikit-learn, intercept, elastic-net

I am using the ElasticNet library from sklearn. I am using one predictor which takes values in the range `[827.559, 827.5625]`.
When I fit the model using this predictor the intercept takes very high values as a result of the very high coefficient of the feature. I tested the model using different `alpha` and `l1_ratio` parameters but the only reasonable results are when either the `alpha=1` and the `l1_ratio=1` (which basically is a Lasso) or `alpha=1` and the `l1_ratio=0.9`. Is this a reasonable result? Why do I have such big values for both intercept and the coefficient?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear because the plot shows a date but in a comment below, the user says the data is not dates.

Comment: I reformulated the question to avoid any misunderstandings

Comment: The extremely narrow range of your predictor relative to its typical values (the ratio is around five orders of magnitude) gets magnified in the calculations (squares are involved), which in double-precision arithmetic wipes out all but five or six significant figures of precision.  That invites numerical instability.  If the library is not internally centering the variables, then you should do so manually, perhaps by re-expressing your predictor as its deviation from 827.56 or some such convenient value. The same applies to all other predictors.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using Sklearn and I am setting the `normalize=True`. I got to check how is taking care of.

Comment: @whuber The problem occurs with `L2` normalization and not with `L1`

Comment: Does anyone have an idea why when I normalize the data using `L1` I do not have any problem?